# How to pass a list of checked checkboxes through confirm modal JQuery Flask

Tags: jquery, flask, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to create a page where user can delete multiple records. These records are in a table and are generated via jinja2 for loop. Each one has a checkbox as a table row with record_id as a value. Where I'm stuck is trying to pass a list of checked values (record_ids) to a modal. 
While I was able to pass variables to modal either via modal id field or data-yourparameter, I can't seem to find a way to pass a list of values that were checked. I think the trick is somewhere in JQuery, but I know very little of it.
My goal is to somehow pass this list of values of checked checkboxes to pass_checkedvalue input in the modal.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have tried so far:

HTML:

```
 <form name="table-form" method="POST">
  {% for record in table %}
    <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="checked[]" value="{{ record.id }}"> 
    </td>
    <td>{{record.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_multidelete" value="btn_display_value" data-target="#multiconfirm-modal"> Delete selected</a>
    </form>


<!-- Modal for Confirm Multi-Delete popup-->
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="multiconfirm-modal">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title">Confirm</h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Are you sure you want to delete these API users?</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer align-items-start">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
<form action="{{ url_for('multidelete') }}" method="POST">
<input name="pass_checkedvalue" type="hidden" value="pass_checkedvalue" id="hidden_checkedinput">
<input class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" name="submit_button" value="Confirm">
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JQuery script:

```
<!-- This script allows checked values to be passed to multi-confirm modal  -->
<script>
$('#multiconfirm-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
var checkedvalue = $('.checked[]:checked').val();
$('#hidden_checkedinput').val(checkedvalue)
});
```

Comment: `checked[]` is a name, not a class.  Put a real class on the checkboxes, change your selector to use it, and map the values into an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a class on the checkboxes (I put `record`), and then select all the records that are checked, map their values into an array, and then join that array into a single string to put in your hidden variable.

```js
$('#multiconfirm-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var checkedValues = $('.record:checked').map(function(){ return this.value; }).get();
  //put the ids in the hidden input as a comma separated string
  $('#hidden_checkedinput').val(checkedValues.join(','));
});
```

```html
<form name="table-form" method="POST">
  {% for record in table %}
  <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" class="record" name="checked[]" value="{{ record.id }}">
    </td>
    <td>{{record.name}}</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  <a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_multidelete" value="btn_display_value" data-target="#multiconfirm-modal"> Delete selected</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you so much Taplar! This has solved it for me!